# Bash: How to save 'find' options into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, find

I need to `chown` and `chmod` some directories and files. To not always duplicate the find filters, I need to save them into a variable.

The following code produces `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

```
findOpts=( \( -path ./.git -o -name .gitignore \) -prune -o )

find . "${findOpts[@]}" chown www-data:www-data {} \+

find . "${findOpts[@]}" -type d -exec chmod 550 {} \+
find . "${findOpts[@]}" -type f -exec chmod 440 {} \+
```

Comment: The example works for me. Just a hint: You don't need to escape the trailing `+`

Comment: Check for your shell (are you really using `bash` or `/bin/sh`?) - see [bashInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) before asking bash related questions

Comment: Even better would be not to re-run `find` three times, but to use the first find to both `chown www-data:www-data "$f"` and `chmod a=,ug+rX "$f"`.  Note that the latter will set the execute/search bit only on directories, without needing a separate `find` for each.

Comment: @bashInfo You are right. That was a problem. But as I see here, there are other good ways to solve the thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your chmod calls are just enabling the `x` bit on directories and disabling it in files, you can use `X` (capital `x`) in chmod (after clearing them first):

```
chmod a=,ug+rX file[..]
```

Also, you can use multiple `-exec` in `find` (at least in `GNU find`), so you could execute find only once, without need to save the options:

```
find . [your filters here] \
    -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;  \
    -exec chmod a=,ug+rX {} \;
```

Comment: Almost - the `=X` permission means _"execute/search only if the file is a directory or **already has execute permission for some user**"_, you need to remove permissions first - `chmod a=,ug+rX` instead.